# SitePages uses System Master Page

Tags: master-page, page-layout, wiki-pages, system-master-page

Bit of a strange issue today.
I wasn't involved in the initial branding/master pages etc of my companie's SP Environment. Anyways, I have a strange issue.

On my site, I have some pages storted under the Pages Library and some under SitePages. Now I know that that SitePages uses Wiki pages and Pages Library allows you to use custom Page Layouts.

My issue howver is, that when I change the the System Master page on a site to a Wide Layout (Predefined Master page), then all pages in SitePages also adopts this look and feel. Pages Library stays unaffected. Surely SitePages (Wiki pages) should only be affted when changing the "Site Master Page" and not when changing "System Master Page "

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior:

The Site Master Page, affects Publishing Pages (/Pages)
The System Master Page, affects Wiki Pages (/SitePages)

http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2011/04/13/site-master-page-vs-system-master-page.aspx