# Restrict sharepoint default pages from using custom master page

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, branding

I am created my custom master page and uploaded using design manager. And applied this master page from **Setting-> Master Page** section of SharePoint.

Now my problem is, this master page is applied to all pages, including SharePoint default pages like `settings.aspx`, `ChangeSiteMasterPage.aspx` etc.

I need to restrict this and I want to apply master page to the pages that I am creating.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, its very much possible.

While selecting the masterpage you have 2 options.

- Site Master Page
- System Master Page

`Site Master Page` will be applied to the pages you are creating.

While `System Master Page` will be applied to all default SharePoint Pages such as `Site Setting`, `Site Contents` etc.

So just configure your custom masterpage to `Site Master Page`. And let `System Master Page` to use default masterpage.

See image.

[image]

In your case you can refer this question [SitePages uses System Master Page](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/31356/30145)

Comment: I tried that, but while selecting "Seattle" in system master page section, then   the pages created by me also inheriting the "Seattle" masterpage. I have created my pages as "wiki" page. Is this make any problem?

Comment: This is default behavior.. Wiki pages are also a system pages. Refer this https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_gossner/2011/04/13/site-master-page-vs-system-master-page/